# Tags shifted left for questions with title that doesn't fit into one line

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

In the [question list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/339911/alexolut?tab=questions) of the profile page when title doesn't fit into single line tags (and last title line) are slightly shifted to the left:

> [image: qlist]

Same for Favorites and Bounties tabs.

Tested on Chrome for Android.

My device: [LG G5](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_g5-7815.php)
Screen resolution: 1440 x 2560

Comment: probably worth mentioning your device resolution, just for the sake of making it easier to replicate

Comment: @JourneymanGeek added device info